# Windows Abnormally High Disk Usage / 100% Disk Usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, speed

I have been experiencing an abnormally high disk usage on Windows 8.1 for a couple of months now that has greatly hindered the speed of my laptop, particularly when a process is retrieving memory from the page-file.

The disk usage often reaches 100% usage and slows the system down to a halt despite only reading and writing at a very slow rate, sometimes never even reaching beyond kilobytes a second.

**Solutions I've attempted:**

- Running `chkdsk /r`
- Disabling prefetch and superfetch (despite not owning an SSD) via their registry keys
- Manually setting the pagefile size
- Disabling the pagefile (Resulting in BSODs every week or so)
- Messing with any hard-drive related BIOS settings (there were none)
- Defragmenting the hard-drive with a rainbow of third-party and official defragmentation software
- Disabled notifications
- Any combination of the above
- Pretty much any other solution I've found searching Google and this website

I've often noticed when it hits 100% disk usage multiple processes are utilizing 0.1% of the disk usage.

Process Monitor shows nothing of value.

Comment: if you see a lot of pagefile activity, it means you need more RAM. to fix high disk IO buy a SSD

Comment: @magicandre1981 When this problem occurs it's not always the pagefile, in fact a lot of the time it's completely random, I have 8GB of RAM. I'd prefer to not buy some new expensive hardware for a problem that I haven't experienced until Windows 8.1.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I understand how hard-drives work, I have a disassembled hard-drive on my desk right next to me. This issue has not affected me in the long experience I've had as a Windows user and a programmer up until just now. I do not have the option of simply buying a new solid state drive and installing it as the problem is affecting my laptop and its architecture might as well be alien to me.
@DavidPostill There is nothing much out of the ordinary in the SMART test, apart from six pending sectors (which `chkdsk /r` didn't help with). Could this be causing the significant speed issues?

Comment: Process explorer from sysinternals might be handy in working out *what* is using your hard drive. That said, pending sector counts are typically a sign of impending, major hard drive failure.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I set up Process Explorer a while ago to show disk usage and IO but it never really showed anything valuable, it's often around 10-20 processes all attempting to read and write on the disk at the same time at ~0.1Mbps resulting in ~800Kbps read and write speeds and a >1000ms disk response time. Sometimes a process may be able to read at ~1Mbps but regardless it's always 100% disk utilization.

Comment: Yeaaah, that's a sign your drive might be on its way out.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thank you, I'll be sure to back it up and read up on laptop hard-drive replacement (or maybe an RMA if I'm still in-warranty).